# jQuery: passing value of a select radiobutton

Tags: jquery

How can I pass the value of the radio button below to the copy_select_val() function?

```
<input type="radio" name="selected_invoice" value="35" onclick="copy_select_val(); return false;">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `this.value` to pass your radio's value to your function :

```
<input type="radio" name="selected_invoice" value="35" 
   onclick="copy_select_val(this.value); return false;">
```

Answer (score 2):

JQuery is about being un-intrusive. Meaning, you don't need Javascript in your html elements directly. This said, you can do this:

```
$("input[name='selected_invoice']:checked").val();
```

If you are using JQuery you should keep the javascript out of the html.

Comment: Understood and will implement!

Answer (score 0):

```
function copy_select_val() {
    alert($(this).val());
}
```

but I'm not user if this will also work on inline handlers like onclick. why dont you just setup a click eventlistener on this button?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="selected_invoice" value="35"
       onclick="copy_select_val(this.defaultValue); return false;">
```